# Running multiple Android Emulators with Intel's HAXM

Tags: android, haxm

When running the Android Emulator under HAXM (x86 image), it seems like only the first instance gets accelerated. The next (identical) instance launched does not use HAXM and is much slower.

Is there any solution to this problem? (Yes, I'm aware of Genymotion which does accelerate multiple emulators on the same machine).

Comment: i managed to run only one instance. second instance not even run and throw error on windows 10